# Launch EC2 Instance using IAM Role on Multiple AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

We have multiple AWS accounts and one management account. We have one web application server in management account. From this server we can create EC2 instances on multiple AWS accounts using secret and access key. However, we would like to launch instance on other AWS accounts using IAM role. Is possible to lauch instances on other AWS accounts using IAM role (Instead of using access and secret key) ?

Comment: Yes, certainly possible, you just need to create a role in the target account and set up a proper trust relationships / assume-role-policy such that your origin account can assume into the target role and grant the target role the appropriate permissions to launch an instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical setup would be:

- Create an **IAM Role** in each 'other' AWS Account

  - Give it the same name in each account to keep things simple
  - Grant it permission to launch an Amazon EC2 instance
- To **launch an instance** in an 'other' account:

  - Assume the IAM Role in the target account (the desired Account ID would be specified in the chosen IAM Role's ARN)
  - Use the returned temporary credentials to launch the EC2 instance

Comment: Thanks @John Rotenstein this works